# Ubuntu 16.04 only works with Private Internet Access now - can't connect without

Tags: networking, internet, vpn

This just happens today - I have been using VPN provided by Private Internet Access (PIA) client. Today after I disconnect with VPN, I can't connect to the internet anymore despite Wifi being connected.

What should I look into to attempt any fixing with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open a Terminal and run this command:

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.pia_manager/
   ```

   If the command is successful, there will be no confirmation, it will 
   simply go to a new line in the Terminal window.
2. This next command removes the start or application menu icon (useful if 
   you're just uninstalling the PIA app and not reinstalling it):

   ```
   rm ~/.local/share/applications/pia_manager.desktop
   ```
3. Reboot

Comment: Just to be clear, will this delete the questioner's Private Internet Access client?  Cause that may not be what they want to do.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely caused the user to lose internet access completely, as without the capability to run the VPN service they won't have been able to get back online, as described in the problem.

Might be best to provide context for the commands that you're offering in order to protect the user.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I'm a bit puzzled as to why you are adding an answer as the question is somewhat old and a good answer has been given and has also been accepted be the question owner.